# Excel Userform forcing label update before continuing sub

Tags: excel, label, userform, vba

[image: Ready indicator]

I have a sub in a spreadsheet to remove individual line items. Because it takes a few seconds to process, I'd like to have a little Ready indicator.

At the moment I've got a small label (see above) called `Lab_Indic`.

When the user clicks remove, it runs the `_Click` sub, which opens with this:

```
With Lab_Indic
    .BackColor = &HFF&
    .Caption = "WORKING"
End With
```

...and closes with this:

With Lab_Indic
    .BackColor = &H8000&
    .Caption = "READY"
End With

But the initial "Working" change only seems to happen if I step through; if I run it normally, it seems to skip past it.

Is there any way to force it to update the label before continuing with the rest? `DoEvents` sounds like it might do the job, but some sources I've looked at suggest that there might be a downside to that approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work nicely, so I'll post it as an answer, but I'm still very interested in any indication of whether it's a *good* solution or not...

```
With Lab_Indic
    .BackColor = &HFF&  ' &H00008000&
    .Caption = "WORKING"
End With
DoEvents
```

I've just added a single `DoEvents` to refresh the label, and it seems to work nicely. I don't know if there are any knockon effects.